# Inequalities for moments of a certain integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, inequalities, stochastic-calculus, gaussian

Let $X(t)$ be a stationary Gaussian process, $EX(t)=0$, the correlation function $R(\tau)$ is given. What bounds from above can be given for the $p$-th moment
($p>0, p \in \mathbb{R}$) of the integral 
$$
  \int_0^T |X(t)|^2 dt?
$$
(The integral is the pathwise integral.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I will be working with the cumulants rather than the moments.*

To simplify the notation let me choose units so that $T\equiv 1$ and discretize time $t_n=n/N$, collecting $X(t_1),X(t_2),\ldots X(t_N)$ in a vector $\vec{X}$. Hence
$$\int_0^1 |X(t)|^2 dt\rightarrow N^{-1}\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}\equiv Z.$$
The correlator $E(\vec{x}\vec{x})=\mathbf{R}$ is an $N\times N$ positive definite Toeplitz matrix: the matrix elements $\mathbf{R}_{nm}=R(|n-m|)\geq 0$ depend only on the time difference because of the stationarity of the Gaussian process.
The cumulant generating function is
$$F(\xi)=\log E(e^{\xi Z})=-\tfrac{1}{2}\log\,{\rm det}\,(1-2\xi \mathbf{R})=-\tfrac{1}{2}{\rm tr}\,\log\,(1-2\xi \mathbf{R}).$$
By expanding the logarithm in powers of $\xi$ we obtain the $p$-th cumulant $\mu_p$ of $Z$ as
$$\mu_p=2^{p-1}(p-1)!\,{\rm tr}\,\mathbf{R}^p.$$
Reverting back to continuous time, and reinstating the time $T$,
$$\mu_p=2^{p-1}(p-1)!\int_0^T dt_1\int_0^T dt_2\cdots \int_0^T dt_p\, R(t_1-t_2)R(t_2-t_3)\cdots R(t_{p-1}-t_{p})R(t_p-t_1).$$

If the correlator $R(t)$ reaches its maximum at $t=0$, then we have the upper bound
$$\mu_p\leq 2^{p-1}(p-1)!T^p R(0)^p.$$
An improved upper bound can be obtained if $R(t)/R(0)$ is maximised by a box function $B(x,a)=1$ if $|x|<a$ and $B(x,a)=0$ if $|x|>a$. Then
$$\mu_p\leq 2^{p-1}(p-1)!T^p R(0)^p f_p(a).$$
The function $f_p(a)$ is the convolution of the box function on the $p$-dimensional hypercube. I don't have a closed form expression for general $p$ --- I have asked at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3233160/87355) --- small-$p$ expressions are

<sub>$$f_2(a)=2a-a^2,\;\;f_3(a)=3a^2-2a^3,$$
$$f_4(a)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3}  \left(-7 a^4+8 a^3\right)&\text{if}\;\;0<a<1/2,\\
\frac{1}{3} \left(2 a^4-16 a^3+24 a^2-8 a+1\right)&\text{if}\;\;1/2<a<1.
\end{cases}$$</sub>

Comment: Yes, but an analogous final bound can be easily obtained for moments as well (just notice that the perfect correlation, i.e., constant trajectories is the worst case scenario by the Minkowski inequality). We gain with cumulants only if we have some bounds for the decay of $R$. Unfortunately, the OP provided us with none...

Comment: Not bad, thanks. But so far we have upper bounds only for integer values of $p$. And the first upper bound seems to be rather far from a sharp estimate - e.g. if $|R(\tau)|$ tends to 0 slowly.